# Is it possible on click of a item in a List View we can go to another list view?

Tags: android-listview

I am able to make first listview but on itemclicklistner its going to another activity but not displaying anything. I am not able to get what is the problem, please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code so we can help you better. It's hard to find a solution if you can't see what's generating the problem! :)